# Subject: Use of Haskell stack, VSCode editor on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell-stack

I am trying to get a simple test project, created by stack, to be usable from within VSCode.

**Stymied!**

- I get red wavies when viewing a file in VSCode, and
- cannot load the module because a variable is not in scope.  This second issue might or might not be related to the first.

Questions at end of this message.

## Details:

### Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Stack 2.5.1
- VSCode 1.55.2
- - Haskell 1.2.0
- - Haskell Syntax Highlighting 3.4.0

### What I have done:

- Installed stack
- Created a project
- Installed VSCode
- Installed Modules
- Opened Folder (relative root of stack project)
- Opened ../my-project/app/Main.hs

### What happened

- File opened fine.
- First line

`module Main where`

got red wavies

Hovering, got a tip with text

```
    (use -v for more information). 
Please ensure that ghcide is compiled with the same GHC installation as the project.cradle
```

### My Questions

- who compiled the relevant ghcide? (hint says GHC 8.10 was used, but by who)
  -- can selection of the GHC be controlled? If so, how?
- How can I control which GHC is used by stack to compile my project?

Answer (score 0):

> - who compiled the relevant ghcide? (hint says GHC 8.10 was used, but by who) -- can selection of the GHC be controlled? If so, how?

The way this is supposed to work is that

1. The Haskell VSCode extension download haskell-language-server for you.
2. The haskell-language-server detects the GHC for your project and downloads GHC for you.
3. The haskell-language-server builds ghcide for you using the GHC which it downloaded.

If your project is a Stack project, then this automatic process should use the Stack resolver to detect the GHC for your project.

I find that running `stack build` in the project directory and then running `code .` in the project directory sometimes helps this automatic process along.

> - How can I control which GHC is used by stack to compile my project?

The best way to do that is by setting the `resolver` in the project `stack.yaml`. https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#resolvers-and-changing-your-compiler-version